# Independent Events - Machine Factory

Tags: probability, statistics

In a machinery factory scenario, we were presented with a testing and identification problem involving machine defects, which leads to an interesting exploration of dependent events in probability. Let’s discuss!

Suppose we have a batch of 5 presses, out of which 3 are defective due to being equipped with inappropriate electric motors. The defectives are tested successively until identified. Let’s denote:

- $N_1$ as the number of tests conducted until the first defective press is identified.
- $N_2$ as the additional number of tests (after identifying the first defective) until the second defective press is identified.

> **An intriguing question arises: Are $N_1$ and $N_2$ independent events?**

At first glance, one might suppose that $N_1$ is independent of $N_2$ since identifying the first defective press might seem irrelevant to the additional tests needed to find the second. However, $N_2$ inherently contains information about $N_1$ due to being "additional" tests, making it somewhat dependent on the realization of $N_1$.

This leads to a puzzling situation where one event appears to be independent of the other, while the other event carries inherent information about the first, challenging the conventional symmetric nature of independence in probability theory.

Would appreciate your insights and clarifications on this apparent paradox! How should we properly interpret the independence or dependence of these events? Is there a deeper probabilistic principle at work here that reconciles this conundrum?

Comment: You are sampling (testing) without replacement.

Comment: @trueblueanil Does that mean that they are both dependent of each other? If so, why?

Comment: If $Y$ is not independent of $X$, then $X$ is is not independent of $Y$.  Knowing the value of $N_2$ affects knowledge of $N_1$.  Consider possible values for $N_1$ if $N_2=2$ or $N_2=3$ or $N_2=4$

Comment: @Henry I know that's the rule of thumb for independecy but in this case why does N1 depend on N2?

Comment: To repeat: knowing the value of $N_2$ affects knowledge of $N_1$.  What is your definition of independence?  What is $\mathbb P(N_1=3 \mid N_2=2)$?

Comment: @Henry Given that $N_1$ is the number of tests to find the first defective item and $N_2$ is the additional number of tests needed to find the second defective item after finding the first, the notation $P(N_1 = 3 | N_2 = 2)$ is somewhat counter-intuitive or confusing, because once we've determined $N_1$, $N_2$ is not influenced by the specific value of $N_1$ other than that it must be a test performed after the first defective is found. Notice the "additional tests" part of the N2 definition.
However, if we stick strictly to the definitions given:

Comment: - $N_1 = 3$ indicates that the first defective was found on the 3rd test.
- $N_2 = 2$ implies that, after finding the first defective, 2 additional tests were performed to find the second defective. Therefore, the second defective was found on the 5th test.

Given these definitions, $P(N_1 = 3 | N_2 = 2)$ can be considered nonsensical, because $N_2$ is defined based on the outcome of $N_1$ (it's the number of additional tests needed after the first defective is found). Knowing $N_2$ doesn’t give us any more information about $N_1$ since it's the additional tests after $N_1$ is realized.

Comment: To better understand my question, you would evaluate this as if we had infinite units.

Comment: You do not have infinite units. *"Suppose we have a batch of 5 presses, out of which 3 are defective".*  If you had a countably infinite number of units of which each had a probability of $\frac35$ of being defective independently of the others, then $N_1$ and $N_2$ would be independent.  But you do not, so they are not

Comment: $P(N_1 = 3 \mid N_2 = 2)=0$ in your original question since there would be no opportunity to find the third defective item.  But $P(N_1=3 \mid N_2=1)=\frac16$ and overall $P(N_1=3)=\frac1{10}$.  So $N_1$ is not independent of $N_2$.

Comment: @Henry Got it! I think I understand now. Thank you for your patience.